# Call an event on Web Control Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am loading my with web controls and loading them based on the URL parameters.

I need to load a gridview if the user is in :&cat=8

My web control has a method which I need to call. One of its parameters is a session which is created only when the category is 8.

Technically I need a way of calling methods within my web control from my page. Placing it on page_load results in an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an event-handler on Load event of the Control itself.

```
private void Page_Load (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
   // Add the following code:
   yourControl.Load += new EventHandler(yourControl_Load);

}


private void yourControl_Load (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //your code here.
}
```

Comment: does this work as a conditional load? My web control only gets loaded when certain conditions are met.

Or I can move the yourControl.Load += new EventHandler(yourControl_Load); to that target place where I validate URL.

Comment: This handler will be called on yourControl.Load event regardless of your condition. Whenever you load the control,the handler will be called.